# converting "string" to "int" with a "/" between it

Tags: c++

I want to the user to type in the current date like, for example:

```
25/05/2011
```

(everything together, just separated with a `/`)

Then I want to separate this input into 3 `int` variables. `D` is the Day, `M` is the month and `Y` is the year.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string TOGETHER;
int D, M, Y;

int main()
{
    cin >> TOGETHER;

    /*
        What should I do here?
    */

    cout << "\n";
    cout << D << "/" << M << "/" << Y << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You tagged 3 languages. For which language do you want a solution?

Comment: The code sample can only be C++ - I removed the other tags.

Answer (score 2):

You could give [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) a try. Or `cin` followed by [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/).

Comment: make sure to mark it as your answer if that's what you used :)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `sscanf` on `TOGETHER.c_str()`, or use `atoi` and break the string to substrings with '/' as the delimiter using `TOGETHER.find` or similar.

Or you can just do the input using `scanf`, but this is not advised (harder to verify valid input).

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/):

```
std::vector<string> DMY;
boost::split (DMY, TOGETHER, boost::is_any_of("/"));
D = boost::lexical_cast<int>(DMY[0]);
M = boost::lexical_cast<int>(DMY[1]);
Y = boost::lexical_cast<int>(DMY[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is (read the comments for explanations):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Converts string to whatever (int)
// Don't worry about the details of this yet, focus on use.
// It's used like this: int myint = fromstr<int>(mystring);
template<class T>
    T fromstr(const std::string &s)
{
     std::istringstream stream(s);
     T t;
     stream >> t;
     return t;
}

std::string TOGETHER;
int D, M, Y;

int main()
{
    std::string temp;
    int pos = 0;
    int len = 0;


    // Get user input
    std::cin >> TOGETHER;


    // Determine length
    for(len = 0; TOGETHER[len] != '/'; len++)
        ;

    // Extract day part from string
    temp = TOGETHER.substr(pos, len);

    // Convert temp to integer, and put into D
    D = fromstr<int>(temp);


    // Increase pos by len+1, so it is now the character after the '/'
    pos += len + 1;

    // Determine length
    for(len = 0; TOGETHER[len] != '/'; len++)
        ;

    // Extract month part from string
    temp = TOGETHER.substr(pos, len);

    // Convert temp to integer, and put into M
    M = fromstr<int>(temp);


    // Increase pos by len+1, so it is now the character after the '/'
    pos += len + 1;

    // Determine length
    for(len = 0; TOGETHER[len] != '/'; len++)
        ;

    // Extract year part from string
    temp = TOGETHER.substr(pos, len);

    // Convert temp to integer, and put into Y
    Y = fromstr<int>(temp);


    std::cout << "\nDate:\n";
    std::cout << "D/M/Y: " << D << "/" << M << "/" << Y << "\n";
    std::cout << "M/D/Y: " << M << "/" << D << "/" << Y << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

See that repetitive code in the middle? It could easily (and should've) have been put into it's own function, which would make this way more awesome. I'll leave that to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Split the String using "/" and strore it in an vector

```
split( strLatLong , '|' ,  Vec_int) ; //Function to call

std::vector<std::int> split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<int> &elems)
 {
     std::stringstream ss(s);
     int item;
     while(std::getline(ss, item, delim))
     {
         elems.push_back(item);
     }

     return elems;
 }

cout << vec_int[0]<<vec_int[1]<<vec_int[2];
```